# Specific rewrite in htaccess if there is a parameter

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress instalation with a different CMS on one folder.

Like this:

```
https://example.com/ => WordPress
https://example.com/en/ => Custom CMS.
```

My htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(en)($|/) - [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This works fine.

Now, I am moving all the content to the WordPress instalation. I need to preview the changes. I need this:

```
https://example.com/ => WordPress
https://example.com/en/ => Custom CMS
https://example.com/en/?preview_id=142&preview=true => WordPress
```

This is, I need to show the WordPress website when there is a "preview" parameter on the URL.

I tried with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !preview=true [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(en)($|/) - [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But It doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As you said `I need to show the WordPress website when there is a "preview" parameter on the URL` and what you did , this `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !preview=true [NC]` will make it in an opposite way so, change it to :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} preview=true [NC]
```

and also ad `?` at the end of target here `RewriteRule . /index.php?` to avoid appending query string and make looping .

Your rules shlould look like this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} preview=true [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php? [L]
```

Comment: Take care with such simple regular expression to test the query string against. It _usually_ works fine, but will break in some situations. You want a more robust expression, something like `(^|&)preview=true(&|$)`.

Answer (score -1):

Please just Delete the .htaccess file.
as soon you delete the file system will create new file auto that will work fine for you.

Comment: This is complete nonsense. "The system", even if it will create a new file (which you don't know), certainly will _not_ create rules to correctly handle the individual requirements the OP pointed out in the question, since "the system" is not a magical one.